# How to replace with Javascript prices between text in array after applying a price discount?

Tags: javascript

I have a table output with 3 columns. Each column contains prices from different client groups (Group A, B and C). Prices format are $19.95 USD, $10.95 USD and so on. I'd need to apply to the output a 20% for Group A, 15% to group B and 10% to group C and then replace with the final price keeping the same format ($price USD).

Script business logic is encrypted so I guess is better to resolve this with Javascript. Please, could someone guide me how to do it?

For:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Price 1</th>
    <th>Price 2</th>
    <th>Price 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="price">$10,95 USD</td>
    <td class="price">$10,95 USD</td>
    <td class="price">$10,95 USD</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Output should be:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Price 1</th>
    <th>Price 2</th>
    <th>Price 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="price">$8,76 USD</td><!-- 20% discount -->
    <td class="price">$9,30 USD</td><!-- 15% discount -->
    <td class="price">$9,85 USD</td><!-- 10% discount -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Grab the price text, convert to number, do math, write it back to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some like this?

```js
var prices = document.querySelectorAll('.price');
var startDiscount = 20;
var minDiscount = 0;
var countOfgroups = 3;
var curGroup = 1;
var discount = startDiscount;

[].forEach.call(prices, function(price) {
  if (discount < minDiscount) {
      discount = minDiscount;
  }
  
  if (curGroup > countOfgroups) {
      curGroup = 1;
      discount = startDiscount;
  }
  
  // get start price for current row
  var priceText = price.innerText;
  
  // get price from the string
  priceText = priceText.replace(/[^0-9\,]/ig, '');
  
  // replace ',' to '.' for count
  priceText = priceText.replace(',', '.');
  
  // get price in cents
  priceText = priceText * 100;
  
  // get price with discount 
  priceText = priceText * (100 - discount)/100;
  
  // rounding the price
  priceText = Math.floor(priceText).toString(); 
  
  // get price in the dollars
  priceText = priceText.slice(0, -2) + '.' + priceText.slice(-2);
  
  // get formatting price
  priceText = '$' + priceText + ' USD';
  
  // write value to the row
  price.innerText = priceText;
  
  discount-=5;
  curGroup++;
})
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Price 1</th>
    <th>Price 2</th>
    <th>Price 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="price">$10,95 USD</td>
    <td class="price">$10,95 USD</td>
    <td class="price">$10,95 USD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="price">$10,95 USD</td>
    <td class="price">$10,95 USD</td>
    <td class="price">$10,95 USD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="price">$10,95 USD</td>
    <td class="price">$10,95 USD</td>
    <td class="price">$10,95 USD</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're freaking amazing, @Anatoly. That's exactly what I need. However, seems to be a little problem. After 4th row, prices are negatives :(

Comment: I guess this happened because of discount. you can add maximum discount and check it :)

Comment: I added max discount checking to my answer

Comment: Negatives problem solved but I am ashamed of not being able to solve the last issue after your help. Your table output is $8,76 USD for 10,95 (that's ok) but my table output is $9855,9 USD for $10,95 USD. Also, your script is applying 10% to price 1, price 2 and price 3. I edited my main question to make it more explanatory.

I've been the last two days trying to fix this but I'm a total Javascript noob. Honestly, thanks a million for your help. I really really appreciate it.

Comment: Now is working but just for the first row. Please, try to add more rows and check it.

Comment: OMG! Thanks a ton! As I can't send you a beer, let me know if you need a hosting account or something in return. Thanks again, Anatoly.